# SymmetricDS: Data is not getting inserted to slave node from Master

Tags: mysql, symmetricds

I am using symmetric DS toll for database synchronization. Whenever i insert some fields into master node it should flow to slave node.

I checked in sym_data table and data is getting created but the same is not getting updated in slave node also there is no outgoing batch with error present.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started symmetricds engine at the master node? It seems like it's not started. Data is inserted into sym_data by db triggers. To have the outgoing batches created symmetricds engine has to run the router job